# How should I update a single input to a Nix flake?

Tags: nixos

I have a Nix flake with several inputs whose URLs are remote git repositories. I want to update one input in `flake.lock`, but not the others; in particular, I want to avoid repinning `nixpkgs`.

When I run `nix flake update`, all inputs are updated. This is probably desirable for correctness. However, I can subsequently roll back part of the changes to `flake.lock`, performing minor surgery, so that only one input is updated.

Is there a blessed or safe way to update only one input? I would accept a way to update a given input and all of its transitive dependencies, if that is the only safe way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unintuitively enough, you use a different command for that. `nix flake update` updates all inputs as you noticed, while you use

```bash
nix flake lock --update-input <name_of_input>
```

to update only a single input. You can also chain several of these in a single command:

```bash
nix flake lock --update-input nixpkgs --update-input nix
```